# Amazon SES - Email address not verified error - Production access enabled

Tags: amazon-web-services, phpmailer, amazon-ses

I am using phpmailer to send SMTP mail with credentials from Amazon SES.
I get the below error.
My production access on SES is enabled.

```
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220 email-smtp.amazonaws.com ESMTP SimpleEmailService-376766033 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com 250-8BITMIME 250-SIZE 10485760 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN 250 Ok 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 Ok 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 Ok 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:354 End data with . 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:554 Message rejected: Email address is not verified. 
SMTP -> ERROR: DATA not accepted from server: 554 Message rejected: Email address is not verified. 
SMTP Error: Data not accepted. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Data not accepted.
SMTP server error: Message rejected: Email address is not verified.
```

Comment: Have you set up the sending domains and email addresses in your AWS console? Can you email yourself at the same address?

Comment: i overlooked this part in the docs" you need to verify that you own the "From" address" - was thinking that with production access i can send from any domain. Thanks for the quick reply! I am now able to send mail from verified domain.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Overlooked the documentation. The From address need to be verified both for the sandbox version and while "production access" is enabled.

Answer (score 12):

You are trying to send email from an email address or domain that you have not verified with Amazon SES. **If you do not yet have production access, you also need to verify the recipient address.**

From: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-response-codes.html